# In views, how to create link to field visible through relationship connection?

Tags: 7, views, entities, tokens

I don’t want to link to the original piece of content (which is a join table) but to the content type which is referenced in the join table.

Using: Views, Entity Reference, Entity Tokens, Token.

I have these content types:
- Person (firstname, lastname, etc.)
- Story (field_story_title, orig copyright, description, etc.) Note: [content:title] is automatically generated and not used.
And this content type which functions as a join table
- PersonStory (field_personstory_person_id, field_personstory_ story_id, relationship [e.g. author].)

The view has Content: Type (= PersonStory)
Relationships have been created
- Story from field_personstory_story_id
- Person from field_personstory_person_id

The view successfully finds Story Title (field_story_title) and Person Name (using [Global: custom text] in concatenation of field_person_lastname, field_person_firstname, etc).

I created a link:
- Added field [content:path] above Story Title on the field list. Checked "Exclude from Display" and expanded "Rewrite results" and only checked "Use absolute link" for this field.
- Added field field_story_title, expanded "Rewrite results" and checked "Output this field as Link" with the Link path: [path] .

The view *looks* just fine with the field_story_title appearing as a link.
[image: View of PersonStory]

**However, clicking the link goes to the record in PersonStory instead of the record in Story**. @skorzh suggested that I investigate replacement pattens in the Rewrite results, but I don't see any tokens which connect to the fields in **Relationships** in the View.
[image: Available Replacement Patterns]

I’ve tried many different patterns and tokens and nothing has worked in details of [field_story_title]. I don't know what the replacement pattern should look like. Is it possible to join replacement patterns? How do I determine what the url should be?

My latest attempt is
[site:url:join:/]/[content-type:name]/[node:field-story-title:name]
but it's not working, naturally.

Thanks.
(Entire post has been updated to reflect my current (lack of) progress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the path field set to use the story relationship. http://cl.ly/372U1S1b2s3V

Comment: Excellent, so simple! Thanks @jphelan. There will be plenty of people grateful for this answer. Of course, it turns out now that's not really what I need to do. :( I need to resolve from the first view to another view, or something else, where I can reference the multiple content types. But that's for another question. I'll come back and post a link to it.

Comment: Here's my evolved question @jphelan. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198809/in-views-can-i-make-a-hyperlink-in-a-view-field-which-resolves-to-another-view

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Place content:path before the field X. Check "Exclude from Display". Expand "Rewrite results" and only check "Use absolute link"
>      for this field.

Did you set properly relationship in this field?

> 2. Field X - Rewrite results - Output this field as Link - Link path: [path] . Do NOT check "Use absolute path" here again.

You can try to write path by entity id token, without additional path field, so in Link path set something like Link path: `node/[node_id]` (see available tokens within Rewrite results)

Comment: I think the relationship is set properly, because the Story Title which displays in the view (Image 1 above) is only present in the original table Story (content type). I have set a relationship which is "A bridge to the content entity that is referenced via field_personstory_story_id".  I don't know much about entity id token, so I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: every token which I tried produced an error message. I can't find any tutorial information about token usage online, might you have some suggestions?