# What are the modules / pages / panels / or other features in Drupal which can be used to display an object which is made up of several content types?

Tags: 7, views, panels

I know views can be used, I have a functioning view which displays the relationship between the content types, using a limited number of fields.

Next I would like the hyperlink to resolve to a display of the **contents** of a "composite object" which includes a number of content types. What can I use?

Using: Views, Entity Reference, Panels, Page Manager

The first view is a **LIST** (alphabetical) of story titles, showing Relationships to other content types, as follows:
- Person (firstname, lastname, etc.)
- Story (field_story_title, orig copyright, description, etc.) Note: [content:title] is automatically generated and not used.
- Series (field_series_title, body)

and these content types which are join tables
- PersonStory (field_personstory_person_id, field_personstory_ story_id, relationship [e.g. author])
- StorySeries (field_storyseries_story_id, field_storyseries_series_id, field_storyseries_logical_order)

Person to Story is many to many, Story to Series is many to many.

[image]

I would like the hyperlink to resolve to a "page" which shows all of the fields from **multiple** content types which relate to that **one** story. This will be quite a lot of data: title, author, copyright, short blurb, synopsis (1K words) and a couple of images. So Views Megarow doesn't feel like an appropriate destination to me.

What are possible methods to show data from multiple content types?

Comment: How will the fields be related to the story. Usually you want to use taxonomies to relate content. As a side note embedding a view in a views field is not a good idea as it is a great way to add a lot of overhead to your view.

Comment: This is an ongoing research problem. There isn't enough information which disseminates how Drupal works. That there might be adequate resources somewhere which someone else knows about is a valid answer, it points the user in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

what's the best way to...

That is subjective. Here is a way to do it, not necessarily the best:

[Views Megarow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_megarow)

> This module allows you to display content coming from a menu callback
>   between two items of a views result set as a modal-like. You can use
>   it to display a preview of your node or to build an administrative
>   form.
>
> Said otherwise, you can dynamically display content below a row of a
>   table of results coming from a view. This content is shown when you
>   click on a link, it means that you can display anything from a preview
>   of your node for instance to a moderation form of an entity.

Comment: I'm not sure what the first sentence of the quote means.   
Even so, I have a whole page worth of information (1,000+ words) which I would like to display from this hyperlink, so I really want to **go** somewhere to display this information. Having a 2+ line pop-up wouldn't serve the purpose.

Comment: you are mistaken, you can pull in whole nodes or even lists of nodes with this module, or anything else. And it is not a popup. It inserts it n a div below the link so the page expands and you can collapse it also, ie accordion

Comment: I can see some occasions where this might be a good way to add a bit of extra data, but in this case, I'm trying to build the a full destination page.

Answer (score 1):

The extra step between Story and Series with StorySeries will make this tricky. Why not link directly to series and person from story with an unlimited entity reference field?

One way that should work with your current configuration is to build a view with a block display that takes the entity reference field (field_storyseries_story_id) as a contextual filter/argument (http://cl.ly/1S330x270j1J) with the default value as the "content id from url" (http://cl.ly/1S2C0l3o0K1q). Then include that block on the stories node and it only show the StorySeries nodes that relate to that story through the reference field. Then you'd need a add a relationship in the view to the series through the field_storyseries_series_id to be able to display the series info. Then do the same with the PersonStory.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. In most cases there is one story which attaches to one or two authors which is part of one series. Unfortunately, not **all* cases. So the relationship is many to many for Person, Story and Series. :(  For the unlimited entity reference fields, are you referring to this module https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_selects or to something else?

Comment: I also found an article by Karen Stevenson, one of the co-creators of CCK, who provides a write up of 7 Module add-ons. Her article titled Entityreference Multiselectors can be found https://www.lullabot.com/articles/entityreference-multiselectors .

Comment: No, in the fields settings set it to unlimited values (http://cl.ly/0z372I2j3J0Q) and then you can add multiple references to your node. (http://cl.ly/413N2j1A0x29)

Comment: I typically use Drupal's built in autocomplete widget but if you like the select field then https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_selects or https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen are both good options to improve the UI for selecting multiple values.

Comment: I found the screen very confusing when I set the link fields to multiple values. I can just imagine how much explainin' I'd have to do to some of our users!  Are you suggesting that I move the link table (as a field) to inside the content type?